# How to find a perpendicular line from a point to a line.

Tags: trigonometry

I have something i am trying to take a consistent measurement of, but the issue is that the sample is not always consistent with rotation.

However from the sample I have a point, and 2 parallel lines.

Given A as the reference point, | | are lines B & C respectively, and D is the measurement point, it would look something like this.

```
            B   C
            |   |
    A-------| D |
            |   |
```

I need to find a way to make sure that the point D in-between lines B & C is always consistent, regardless of rotation, using the reference point A.

So my thought is to make a line that intersects Line B from Point A.
This Line must be made to always be perpendicular.
I then take the middle point of this new line that falls in-between lines B & C which will always give me a consistent location for D.

Only how do I figure out the slope to give the line from point a to Line B so that the line is perpendicular to Line B and C?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The slope of a perpendicular is the negative reciprocal of the slope of the line.  So if the slope of line B is $20$, the slope of $AB$ is $\frac {-1}{20}$.  If $B$ and $C$ are parallel, they have the same slope and this will be perpendicular to $C$ as well.

Answer (score 0):

The distance from point $A$ to line $B$ is minimized when the line through $A$ is perpendicular to line $B$.

Given the slope $m$ of line $B$, use slope $-{1\over m}$ (the slope at which the lines will be perpendicular) and find the line with that slope that passes through point $A$ (located at $(x_0,y_0)$):

$$(y-y_0)=-{1\over m}(x-x_0)$$

Solving for the $b$ term in the form $y=ax+b$:

$$y=-{1\over m}x+{x_0\over m}+y_0$$

In other words, $b={x_0\over m}+y_0$.